# How to inherit slots with svelte components?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, svelte

There is a component `<Bar>` that inherits from a component `<Foo>`.

The `<Foo>` component defines a slot named `content` with a fallback content. The `<Bar>` component also defines a slot named `content` with a different fallback content.

```
<!-- Foo.svelte -->
<slot name="content">
  foo fallback
</slot> 

<!-- Bar.svelte -->
<script>import Foo from './Foo.svelte'</script>
<Foo>
    <span slot="content">
        bar fallback
    </span>
</Foo>
```

The `<Bar>` component displays the fallback when called with `<Foo/>` but it does not display the custom content when called with `<Bar><span slot="content">bar custom</span></Bar>`.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<Foo/>
<!-- prints 'foo fallback': OK -->

<Foo>
    <span slot="content">foo custom</span>
</Foo>
<!-- prints 'foo custom': OK -->

<Bar/>
<!-- prints 'bar fallback': OK -->

<Bar>
    <span slot="content">bar custom</span>
</Bar>
<!-- prints 'bar fallback': KO - I would have expected 'bar custom' -->
```

Note that this code is oversimplified, and my real-world usecase is a bit more complex than this, and I need to use slots there.

The fiddle: https://svelte.dev/repl/5c525651eb8b4f60a6a696c1bd19f723

Comment: You aren't defining a slot for `Bar` so all that is ever rendered is `Foo`'s slot. A clearer way to do this is to define a property for `Bar` [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/2174d98aeee94d1091ae66052854c01c?version=3.44.3)

Comment: Thanks. This is an oversimplified sample of code to expose my issue, in my real-world usecase a property is just not powerful enough and I do need to use slots.

Comment: Fair enough, though it's a little unclear how you expect the nested slots to work. Regardless, you are passing slot content to `Bar` but Bar doesn't define a slot, here's one option which still renders slot content passed to `Bar` inside `Foo`: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2174d98aeee94d1091ae66052854c01c?version=3.44.3) (looks like REPL site is broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to render slot content passed to `Bar` in the slot defined by `Foo`, but currently you haven't defined a slot in `Bar` so there is nowhere for the passed content to be used, thus the fallback value is always passed to `Foo`.

A solution might look something like the following, defining a `content` slot in `Bar` *inside* the span passed to `Foo`'s content slot.

```
// App.svelte

<script>
    import Foo from './Foo.svelte'
    import Bar from './Bar.svelte'
</script>

Expected: <em>bar custom</em><br>
<Bar>
    <span slot="content">bar custom</span>
</Bar>
```

```
// ./Bar.svelte

<script>
  import Foo from './Foo.svelte';
</script>

<Foo>
  <span slot="content">
    <slot name="content">bar fallback</slot>
  </span>
</Foo>
```

```
// ./Foo.svelte

<slot name="content">
  foo fallback
</slot>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2174d98aeee94d1091ae66052854c01c?version=3.44.3)

Comment: Thank you. This seems OK, but that would break with a third level of inheritance. For instance, with a `<Baz>` component inheriting from `<Bar>` and without a fallback slot, I cannot achieve to use a custom content. https://svelte.dev/repl/58c4dadc8d884abd8c46e4f8edfa6ea3
Although, that might be another issue.

Comment: Well you've just replicated the problem you had in the `Foo` `Bar` inheritance by not specifying a slot in `Baz`. Without more context for how your real compenents interact I can't really offer more.

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the answers were pretty close.  I believe you can fix it by creating a slot with both content and name being the same value.  Building off of your example ([Repl with full 3rd level inheritance](https://svelte.dev/repl/232a3771df3a4ca292e1bbfa42941128?version=3.44.3)),

```html
<!-- Foo.svelte -->
<slot name="content">
  foo fallback
</slot>
```

```html
<!-- Bar.svelte -->
<script>import Foo from './Foo.svelte'</script>
<Foo>
  <slot name="content" slot="content">
    bar fallback
  </slot>
</Foo>
```

By doing it this way, we are both passing the slot through and including our new fallback.

If you were looking to make sure the span is there, that can be done by either putting it inside or outside of the `slot` depending on your use case.

```html
<!-- Bar.svelte -->
<script>import Foo from './Foo.svelte'</script>
<!-- option 1-->
<Foo>
  <span>
    <slot name="content" slot="content">
      bar fallback
    </slot>
  </span>
</Foo>
<!-- option 2-->
<Foo>
  <slot name="content" slot="content">
    <span>
      bar fallback
    </span>
  </slot>
</Foo>
```